# Using GWT/GAE Blobstore as a database

Tags: database, google-app-engine, gwt, blobstore

Can the Blobstore in GWT/GAE be used as a database? Or is a new Blobstore created each time I launch the application? I would like to store information without losing it when the application is closed. But I can't seem to find a way to name a Blobstore and then reference it by its ID. Thanks!

Comment: GWT and GAE are separate products.  Blobstore is part of GAE. Blobstore is supposed to be a complement to the App Engine _datastore_, which as you might guess, stores data, much like a database.

Comment: @calvin You should post that as an answer.

Comment: all i need to do is write a String to a text file. Using a datastore seems like such an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is store a string I'd still suggest using the datastore.

Here's the complete python source to an App Engine app that retrieves, modifies, and stores some text in the datastore:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp, db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util    

class TextDoc(db.Model):
    text = db.TextProperty(default="")

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        my_text_doc = TextDoc.get_or_insert('my_text_doc')

        my_text_doc.text += "Blah, blah, blah. "
        my_text_doc.put()

        self.response.out.write(my_text_doc.text)


def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                         debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you're working in Java it would be more verbose, but similar.

Comment: Thank you very much Calvin. I actually am working in Java. I'm currently playing with the BlobStore, which seems like it may workout for me. :)